# How Can I merge two files when keeping unmatch values?

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a method to merge some files based on the first 2 rows. But I don't want to exclude the uniq values, I wish they stay so I could make a final unique file.

I tried using this command:

```
join <(sort 1) <(sort 2) | tac | awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$2}' | column -t
```

But it merge and output only the stuff that match.

For example, this data of file 1:

```
mm1 36307733 36324029 1.45947622984395
mm1 36530188 36547201 -1.05469327277336
mm1 37874801 37890411 1.1818111527155
mm1 39551296 39577405 1.03024743095568
mm1 40465552 40500854 1.69797988062545
```

file 2:

```
mm1 17601901 17630939 -1.02477154457324
mm1 21511933 21513056 -1.01776484266642
mm1 23995939 24005656 -1.29725218483742
mm1 24612407 24612700 -1.5481572503361
mm1 24612775 24613119 -1.69044737891815
```

file 3:

```
mm1 21218575 21230167 -1.0792454238353
mm1 23995939 24005656 -1.38350179201041
mm1 24612407 24612700 -1.99368917819954
mm1 24612775 24613119 -1.27503764730879
mm1 36140027 36244720 1.15136681818451
```

In the output file rows that are not contained in other files should be marked 0

output.file

```
                           File 1   File 2  File 3
mm1 36307733    36324029    1.45947622984395    0   0
mm1 6530188     36547201   -1.05469327277336    0   0
mm1 37874801    37890411    1.1818111527155     0   0
mm1 39551296    39577405    1.03024743095568    0   0
mm1 40465552    40500854    1.69797988062545    0   0
mm1 17601901    17630939    0   -1.02477154457324   0
mm1 21511933    21513056    0   -1.01776484266642   0
mm1 23995939    24005656    -1.29725218483742   -1.38350179201041
mm1 24612407    24612700    -1.5481572503361    -1.99368917819954
mm1 24612775    24613119    0   0   -1.27503764730879
mm1 36140027    36244720    0   0    1.15136681818451
```

Comment: Please show what you have already tried, thanks.

Comment: So you posted a question and accepted the first answer you got even though that answer uses a whole bunch of GNU-specific tools and pipelines specifically said `It's actually a job for awk.`. OK, good luck!

Comment: Don't get it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

Here is an awk solution that is not fixed to three files

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{c++} {k=$1 FS $2 FS $3; keys[k]; a[k,c]=$4} 
                END{for(key in keys) 
                      {printf "%s", key FS; 
                       for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
                           printf "%s", (a[key,i]?a[key,i]:0) FS; 
                       print ""}}' file{1,2,3} | 
  sort | column -t

mm1  17601901  17630939  0                  -1.02477154457324  0
mm1  21218575  21230167  0                  0                  -1.0792454238353
mm1  21511933  21513056  0                  -1.01776484266642  0
mm1  23995939  24005656  0                  -1.29725218483742  -1.38350179201041
mm1  24612407  24612700  0                  -1.5481572503361   -1.99368917819954
mm1  24612775  24613119  0                  -1.69044737891815  -1.27503764730879
mm1  36140027  36244720  0                  0                  1.15136681818451
mm1  36307733  36324029  1.45947622984395   0                  0
mm1  36530188  36547201  -1.05469327277336  0                  0
mm1  37874801  37890411  1.1818111527155    0                  0
mm1  39551296  39577405  1.03024743095568   0                  0
mm1  40465552  40500854  1.69797988062545   0                  0
```

doesn't require array or arrays (real multi-dimensional arrays).

Comment: Amazing! I liked your other picture karakfa! You really are an awk master. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: wait until the real master chips in.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU bash, cut, GNU grep, GNU sort and column:

```
#!/bin/bash

cut -d " " -f 1-3 file1 file2 file3 | sort -u | while read -r line; do
  echo -n "$line: "
  (
    grep -Po "$line"'\K.*' file1 || echo " 0 "
    grep -Po "$line"'\K.*' file2 || echo " 0 "
    grep -Po "$line"'\K.*' file3 || echo " 0 " 
  ) | tr -d '\n'
  echo
done | column -t
```

Output:

```
mm1  17601901  17630939  0                  -1.02477154457324  0
mm1  21218575  21230167  0                  0                  -1.0792454238353
mm1  21511933  21513056  0                  -1.01776484266642  0
mm1  23995939  24005656  0                  -1.29725218483742  -1.38350179201041
mm1  24612407  24612700  0                  -1.5481572503361   -1.99368917819954
mm1  24612775  24613119  0                  -1.69044737891815  -1.27503764730879
mm1  36140027  36244720  0                  0                  1.15136681818451
mm1  36307733  36324029  1.45947622984395   0                  0
mm1  36530188  36547201  -1.05469327277336  0                  0
mm1  37874801  37890411  1.1818111527155    0                  0
mm1  39551296  39577405  1.03024743095568   0                  0
mm1  40465552  40500854  1.69797988062545   0                  0
```

PS: It's actually a job for awk.